# ModX friendly url has a bad format

Tags: friendly-url, modx

Sorry, this is probably a very basic question, but I'm new to ModX and haven't been able to find an answer.

I am trying to get friendly urls working, but right now, all my urls are showing up like

```
http://localhost/modx/modx-2.2.13-pl/"http://localhost/modx/modx-2.2.13-pl/other.html
```

instead of the expected

```
http://localhost/modx/modx-2.2.13-pl/other.html
```

I probably don't have some system setting set correctly; any help would be greatly appreciated...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sounds like you've forgotten to add

```
<base href="[[++site_url]]" />
```

To your head.

At least that is the first thing that comes to mind.

Comment: Thanks Optimus. It turns out that the problem was caused by having the no-cache "!" in my base; once I kicked that out, all works well...

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like you're generating the links with full path, are you doing them yourselves or is it Wayfinder or some snippet? And why do you have a " there in the middle of the string?

The basic idea is to use a base_href consisting of your root, `http://localhost/modx/modx-2.2.13-pl/`, and then construct links like `[[~[[+idToPageYouWantToLink]]]]`.